# Spawn detached electron/node process within built Electron App

Tags: node.js, shell, process, electron, spawn

I'm building some sort of `Server Manager` that will mainly be used to configure processes in an "user friendly" environment.

The interface is pretty basic, and allows the creation of servers, configuring and starting/stopping them:

[image]

I am using `forever-monitor` to keep track of the instances, and manage the lifecycle of each server. That is working just great when I run `electron` directly from my app folder.

However, when I tryed to build and run it from a compiled app, each spawn of a new server instance was actually launching a new `electron` instance.

I then thought to specify the `command` in the spawn process, but that lead me to this error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:949:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

And the file where I manage the processes and spawns them is this:
https://github.com/ivanseidel/TournamenterApp/blob/master/controllers/ServerRunner.js#L41-L86

Comment: Did you ever solve the `spawn node ENOENT` error? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Yep, check it out: https://github.com/ivanseidel/TournamenterApp/blob/master/controllers/ServerRunner.js#L72-L145